# How to start Background Thread?

Tags: ios4

```
I have a table view in after every navigation that tableview contain difference value every time.
```

`enter code here`so i write my code in ViewWillAppear and now i want to start background thread so please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the following to run the threads in background NSOperation, NSinvocationOperation or performselector.

[This](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/02/16/cocoa-tutorial-nsoperation-and-nsoperationqueue/) is a very good link and it also gives you a good comparisons of the above types.